# Cannot Access Laravel via HTTPS

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, https

I am having an issue accessing my site using https. Here is the layout

`domain.com -> Has SSL certificate -> works perfectly`

`subdomain.domain.com -> Has SSL certificate covering the subdomain -> ISSUES` - This subdomain has an A DNS record looking at a Linode Server IP address hosting my Laravel

Accessing `http://subdomain.domain.com/` works but shows no padlock

Accessing `https://subdomain.domain.com/` throws `cannot be reached` with Laravel giving the `Invalid request (Unsupported SSL request)` error

Here is my `ENV`

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://subdomain.domain.com

SERVER_PORT=443
SERVER_HOST=<linodeIPAddressHere>
```

There is nothing in the `boot()` AppServiceProvider.php and I have tried many solutions. My Linode Firewall is allowing port 443 inbound and outbound, the SSL certificate is 100% installed using SSL checker websites. I'm stuck here. I'm happy to troubleshoot anything as I'll be working on this until I can find a fix.

UPDATE

I am running Laravel Jetstream 9.52.9, PHP 8.1.2-1 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I don't have Nginx installed or anything Apache wise. Just installed Composer, PHP, git and the project to get it up and running

**Final Update**
My mistake was not installing Nginx and trying to cut the corner just to get the prototype to work. It is much easier to do it properly.

Comment: Please share your installed Laravel framework version and PHP version.

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I have added this to the post

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to edit .htaccess file in public folder of your domain ... **If on APACHE** ->  Something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css|php)$">
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header unset ETag
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires "Wed, 12 Jan 1980 05:00:00 GMT"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I'll give this one a go now

Comment: This still giving the same error in the terminal